# Crontab to schedule a recurring Python script

Tags: python, cron

I am using Cron to schedule a script everyday. Here is my code:

```
45 10 * * * Documents/test.py
```

And the script is just a

```
print 'Hello'
```

I use this command line to launch it:

```
 crontab crontab.txt
```

The error is the following:

```
"crontab.txt":1: bad minute
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you check the text file from the command line using `cat` command that it is actually what you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

Florian, the error output you're receiving of `"crontab.txt":1: bad minute` means that the first variable of your cron entry is incorrect.  However, your posted cron entry of `45 10 * * * Documents/test.py` looks correct to me, and works for me.

I was able to reproduce your error by creating a `crontab.txt` file with contents of `61 10 * * * Documents/test.py`, where clearly the 61st minute is a "bad minute".

Are you certain your `crontab.txt` file is exactly as you posted, `45 10 * * * Documents/test.py`?  You need to ensure that the first variable of your crontab entry is an integer from 0 to 59.